# setTimeOut to delay load of href from url in html - Not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a link on all pages and every time the user clicks it I want to delay the next page load from the `href` with the `<a>` tag. I have tried to grab the link in the `<a>` tag in the HTML then tried to delay it but the timeout won't work. Can anyone kindly help?

```
var link = document.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href')

setTimeout(function() {
  location.href = link
}, 4000);
```

Comment: timeout is unconditional here

Comment: Did you prevent the default action of clicking the link? Also, please describe the issue, "_not working_" doesn't tell anything about the problem ...

Answer (score 2):

This will help you I believe:

```
const a = document.querySelector('a');

a.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const link = e.target.href;

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.open(link)
  }, 1000)
})
```

[Working example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Madebyspeedster/4xfjeLaw/17/)

Comment: The error "_Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code._" means that the relevant code should be in the question. Not that you should format the link itself as code. For more information see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) You can [create a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if you want your example to be runnable.

Comment: Thanks Tim. 

I added it to my code but the delay still doesn't happen.

Comment: It should, can u pls share the example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ( document.getElementById('primaryCTA') != null) {
var primaryCTA = document.getElementById("primaryCTA").onclick = showSpinner;

function showSpinner() { 
var spin = document.getElementById("tick-animation-small");
if(spin.style.display == 'inline-flex')
spin.style.display = 'none';
else
spin.style.display = 'inline-flex';

var  saving = document.getElementById("mini-spinner-copy"); 
if(saving.innerHTML ==  "Continue" )
    saving.innerHTML = "Saving progress"; 
else
    saving.innerHTML ==  "Continue";
  
    var element = document.getElementById("mini-spinner-copy");
    element.classList.add("fadeIn");     
  
 

 const a = document.querySelector('a');

 a.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const link = e.target.href;

   setTimeout(() => {
      window.open(link)
   }, 3000)
 })
 
  
};
```

}

Comment: are us sure you've selected only one element "a"?

Comment: BTW, can u pls move  const a = document.querySelector('a');

 a.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const link = e.target.href;

   setTimeout(() => {
      window.open(link)
   }, 3000)
 }) 
outside  somewhere globally

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it works on all a links except the one with an id of primaryCTA

Comment: nice, glad that it helps.